# Postgres module not found in Airflow?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, airflow, mwaa

For some reason I'm having an issue importing from my airflow postgres packages. Any ideas?

Error:

[image: Error image]

Modules:

[image: imported modules image]

Requirement.txt file with packages:

[image: requirements.txt image]

Answer (score 0):

If you use Airflow 2.0+ the you should only install `airflow-providers-postgres[aws]`, no need to install backports packages.